# Deploying Flask app on NginX / Passenger server on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in production mode on VPS

Tags: nginx, flask, ubuntu-16.04, passenger, vps

**Question 1: What is the problem?**:
Following [this tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/python/) I  installed `Nginx` and `Passenger` on Ubuntu 16.04 to run Python  `Flask` app and I run into this issue: When I visit my server at http://hXXXXXXX.stratoserver.net/ in the browser I am getting this error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

**Question 2: Passenger version and integration mode**:
Passenger open source 6.0.4 + Nginx

**Question 3: OS or Linux distro, platform (including version)**:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
$ uname -a
Linux hXXXXXXX.stratoserver.net 4.4.0-042stab141.3 #1 SMP Fri Nov 15 22:45:34 MSK 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Question 4: Passenger installation method**:
Nginx + Phusion APT repo

**Question 5: Your app's programming language**:
Python 3.7.6 + Flask 1.1.1

**Question 6: Are you using a PaaS and/or containerization? If so which one?**
No

**Question 7: Anything else about your setup that we should know?**
I have a VPS at strato.nl with Ubuntu 16.04 installed, and the host address is: http://hXXXXXXX.stratoserver.net/ and I was following "Deploying a Python app with Passenger to production" [tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/python/) making the following choices in the tutorial:

```
1. Linux/Unix
2. Nginx
3. Passenger open source
4. Python installed via LinuxBrew (Python v3.7.6)
5. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
6. Demo Flask app from github
```

The demo Flask app was cloned from Phusio Passenger github like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/phusion/passenger-python-flask-demo.git
```

Running  `passenger-memory-stats` gives:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/passenger-memory-stats
Version: 6.0.4
Date   : 2020-01-29 13:12:15 +0100
------------- Apache processes -------------
*** WARNING: The Apache executable cannot be found.
Please set the APXS2 environment variable to your 'apxs2' executable's filename, or set the HTTPD environment variable to your 'httpd' or 'apache2' executable's filename.


---------- Nginx processes -----------
PID    PPID   VMSize    Private  Name
--------------------------------------
23320  1      174.9 MB  0.8 MB   nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
23325  23320  174.9 MB  0.8 MB   nginx: worker process
### Processes: 2
### Total private dirty RSS: 1.54 MB


----- Passenger processes -----
PID    VMSize    Private  Name
-------------------------------
23309  445.7 MB  2.5 MB   Passenger watchdog
23312  672.3 MB  7.5 MB   Passenger core
### Processes: 2
### Total private dirty RSS: 9.98 MB
```

When I run the app locally on the server everything works as expected:

```
$ python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Then in another terminal:

```
$ curl localhost:5000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background: #f0f0f0;
      margin: 4em;
    }

    .main {
      background: white;
      border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;
      border-radius: 8px;
      padding: 2em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <section class="main">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to the Passenger Flask example app.</p>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

So it looks like locally all works fine.
However when I visit http://hXXXXXXX.stratoserver.net/ in the browser I got an error page like described above.
The nginx error `/var/log/nginx/error.log` contains the following:

```
App 29730 output: from flask import Flask, render_template
App 29730 output: ImportError
App 29730 output: :
App 29730 output: No module named flask
```

So it looks like the script cannot find the packages I previously installed for Python3 and it uses Python2 packages. Printing `sys.version` in server response gives:

```
sys.version: 2.7.17 (default, Dec 24 2019, 17:49:09)
```

I installed all my packages for Python3 so I need my script on the server uses Python3. **How can I setup the Python version and Python libraries in NginX/Passenger?**

My demoapp config is:

```
$ vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/demoapp.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hXXXXXXX.stratoserver.net;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/demoapp/code/public;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

What are the passenger / Nginx settings that I need to set to successfully run a Flask application? 
How can I set Passenger / Nginx to use Python3 and Python3 site-packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the path to Python's binary in the app's config file (in the server context). So now my config file demoapp.conf looks like:

```
$ vi /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/demoapp.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hXXXXXXX.stratoserver.net;

    # Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
    root /var/www/demoapp/code/public;
    
    # Tell Nginx and Passenger which Python executable to use
    passenger_python /Users/<username>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/envs/v3.9.2/bin/python3;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

And everything works as expected. Please note this line:

```
passenger_python /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/python3;
```

which points to the Python v3.7.6 binary I installed with linuxbrew.

Another option is to use Python virtual environment where you can also specify the Python version you want to use.